# How to copy excel sheet automatically into outlook

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I am trying to copy an active Excel sheet Range a1:k49 automatically from Excel into Outlook to be sent as email.

I also have a logo at the top of the Excel sheet but when this code copies into outlook the logo picture does not show.

```
Sub CovercopypasteOutlook()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("a1:k49")


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = ""
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        '.Send
    .display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a simpler method to copy the range and paste directly in to an outlook MailItem, without using a `PublishObject`.  Do not use ANY of the suggestion above

I am thinking simply copy the sheet's used range and then use the mailItem's WordEditor, like:

```
'On Error Resume Next  '## GET RID OF THIS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING. YOU DON'T.
With OutMail
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = ""
    'HTMLBody = RangeToHtml(rng)  '### GET RID OF THIS BECAUSE IT IS NOT NEEDED###
    '.Send
.display
End With

'### ^^^ ADD THESE THREE LINES RIGHT BELOW THE LINES ABOVE ^^^ ###
Dim doc As Object
Set doc = OutApp.ActiveInspector.WordEditor
doc.Range(1, 1).Paste
'### END OF ADDED LINES ###
```

Results with:

[image]

This does not use your `RangeToHtml` function so it will not do that formatting of the markup that you do with the FSO, but this should be enough to get you started, I think.

Comment: Is there a way I can attach the excel sheet so people can actually try to fix the code I am not having any luck

Comment: I made a revision to my answer, but if you still can't figure it out, you can always revise your original question to include the code you are *currently* attempting to use.

Comment: I thought I did that at the beginning I described my exact situation and the range I have with in my excel sheet.  I have had several suggestions of things to try, but the problem is I am not one that understands this stuff.  I can copy complete versions but to make additions and revise certain code issues I have no idea what I am doing.  One of the other forums suggested I post here but on that site I can attach my sheet so the people trying to help can actually see the problem first hand.  Sorry that I have no idea what to do on my own.  Thanks for your help though I appreciate it.

Comment: I have included explanation in my answer above about which line(s) of your code are problematic. I have used your **exact** code to identify the problems and have shown you what needs to be changed.  What part of my answer is not clear?

Comment: Once I started making the changes I would try as I went to see the progress.  What I noticed is that it started coping the range and pasting it into a new worksheet, then it would also open up outlook and a blank message is there with my signature, Once I removed the “'HTMLBody = RangeToHtml(rng)” it quit pasting to the new worksheet and just opens outlook with signature. I also added those 3 lines for which you were not specific where they went and still does not work.

Comment: What do you want me to do man? I've explained this to you. There are two solutions. You can't implement them both simultaneously.